# Formatting options in textArea element in Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

**Angular 5**

I want to provide features such as bullet points, formatting text, etc. in a text area element of my page. Is there any way to do this while using Angular material elements?

Answer (score 1):

```
You can't do that but there is another way. delete the textarea.use contenteditable="true".using contenteditable="true" you can edit in your textarea section.

'<section id="textarea" contenteditable="true">
<ul>
    <li>List item here</li>
    <li>List item here</li>
    <li>List item here</li>
    <li>List item here</li>
</ul>

</section>'
```

Comment: Thanks. Would that be in theme with the remaining material components though?

Comment: you can put it with with any parent div or html element after this area become editable.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out